# How can I read a text file with 2 columns in Swift?

Tags: swift, file, import, swift3

I have 2 problems:

1. I need to open the text file
2. I need to read in data (organized as 2 columns) and store into either 2 arrays or a multi-dimensional array. The 2 columns are numeric x-y pairs (see below for screenshot of the data), so whatever is easier will work for me, I just need to make sure that the first x-value corresponds to the first y-value.

[image]

**My attempt:**

I tried using this code that I found on this website, but it's giving me errors that I can't figure out:

```
let path:String = Bundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("README", ofType: "txt")!
 textView.text = String(contentsOfFile: path,
                 encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
                 error: nil)
```

**Errors for the code for the first problem:**

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Bundle'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'textView'

Comment: The code you posted is not Swift 3 code.

Comment: @rmaddy right...

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem this works:

```
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "myResource", withExtension: "txt")
    let text = try? String(contentsOf: url!)
    print(text ?? "")
```

for the unresolved identifier part make sure the definition of textView is correct and the source code has your application as its target

for your second problem:

let's say we have these three lines in our text file:
first-one\n
second-two\n
third-three

```
   var pairs = [(Double,Double)]()

    for line in (text?.components(separatedBy: "\n").dropFirst())!{
        if line != "" {
            let sep = # separator is here
            let words = line.components(separatedBy: sep)
            pairs.append((Double(words[0])!,Double(words[1])!))
        }
    }


    // for reading of the values

    for pair in pairs{
        print(pair) // equivalent to : (pair.0,pair.1)
    }
```

Comment: This gives an error pointing to the line `pairs.append((words[0],words[1]))`. The error is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Comment: I have just tested it agin , it works. Are your words separated by hyphen?

Comment: I put my `samplepotential.txt` file in the folder that holds all of the other files for the current Xcode project and also dragged the `samplepotential.txt` file into the project.

Comment: they are numeric values separated by a space

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the file: http://imgur.com/a/nDRCt I've also added it to the question

Comment: The code is updated to work with doubles and space separator

Comment: Looks like it gives the same error pointing to the same line.

Comment: I tinkered around with different numbers of spaces (because the file I'm reading from looks to have some extra spaces in between the numbers) but it still doesn't work with 2,3,4 spaces.

Comment: I think it's because of the first line (the first line is of type string not double) so I dropped the first line , now it's all lines but first and all doubles.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news but....same error pointing to the same line :(

Comment: Wait I think this might be important. This is what the console outputs when I print out the constant `words`: http://imgur.com/a/j58Ut

Comment: Got it. Just needed to change `let words = line.components(separatedBy: " ")` to `let words = line.components(separatedBy: "\t")`. Thank you for the assist! Feel free to update the code to show what worked.